# PostgreSQL Full Text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I need to use Full Text Search with Postgresql but I don't find the way to look for a list of words from a table (using `ts_query`) against an indexed text field (`ts_vector` data type). Is `ts_query` just able to process a few words or can process also multiple values that come from a table?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A `to_tsquery` can search for multiple tokens by splitting the tokens with a &: `to_tsquery('foo & bar & baz')`. So you could retrieve your list of words from your table and feed them (as *tokens*) to the `to_tsquery' function, separated by ampersands. Yet ... a few code examples could help to better illustrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: `SELECT * FROM table , to_tsquery(SELECT words FROM another_table) query WHERE Table.indexed_text_field @@ query;` I think your solution would be great, but I don't know how to feed `to_tsquery`.

Comment: Formulated an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to formulate an answer according to the comments given on the question (if I understand your request correctly).

### Problem

You are trying to do a full text search on the table `tableA`, column `indexed_text_field` (a `tsvector` type) based on words that are stored as `text` in another table `tableB` in a column called `words`.

### Solution

First, if you wish to feed PostgreSQL multiple tokens (individual words) during a full text search you have two functions at your disposal:

- to_tsquery()
- plainto_tsquery()

In the first function you need to split each given token with an ampersand (&). The second function can be fed any string of text and it will chop it into tokens for you. More info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-textsearch.html).

Your challenge is that you wish to select matches based on words present in another table. This can be done in different ways, for example via a simple (INNER) JOIN:

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM tableA a, tableB b WHERE a.indexed_text_field @@ to_tsquery(b.words);
```

Or if you have multiple words in the `words` column you should most likely be using the `plainto_tsquery()` function to keep things simple:

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM tableA a, tableB b WHERE a.indexed_text_field @@ plainto_tsquery(b.words);
```

Yet, if you *must* use the more low-level `to_tsquery()` version:

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM tableA a, tableB b WHERE a.indexed_text_field @@ to_tsquery(replace(b.words, ' ', '&'));
```

In the latter you replace all spaces between the words with an ampersand, thus making them separate tokens. Mind the index usage on the last one though, as you might need to create an expression index on the usage of the `replace()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer, it has been really useful for me. Now I'm facing some performance problems while running these codes, while `indexed_text_field`is a 23 Million record table and `words` is a 140 record table, it's taking more than 5 hours to finish. Do you think it's correct?

Comment: You are very welcome. If the answer helped you, please accept it as so. Regarding the performance,  5 hours is awfully long for this run, without a proper look at your database setup my first guess would be that your tsvector data misses a database index (Gist or Gin). What kind of indexes do you have on your data?

Comment: I'm using GIST for both fields.

Comment: Well, the next step is to see what the planner is doing then ... what is the output using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the same query that took 5 hours (Btw, which query of the above did you run)?